# Dart StageXL sprite color change on mouse click

Tags: dart, sprite, stagexl

I am relatively new to both StageXL and Dart and I am having difficulty changing the color of a Sprite on a mouse click.  Currently I am just referencing the sprite and calling the graphics fillColor() method however nothing changes. Any ideas on how to change individual Sprite lines by mouse click?

```
class GameBoard
{
    Stage stage;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    var circle;
    var line;

    GameBoard(Stage s)
    {   
        this.stage = s;
        this.xPos = 100;
        this.yPos = 100;
        this.circle = new Sprite();
        this.line = new Sprite();
    }

    Sprite generateDots(int x, int y, int size)
    {
        circle.graphics.circle(x,y,size);
        circle.graphics.fillColor(Color.Black);
        circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reactCircle);
        return circle;
    }

    Sprite generateHorzLines(int x, int y)
    {
        line.graphics.beginPath();
        line.graphics.moveTo(x, y);
        line.graphics.lineTo(x+100, y);
        line.graphics.closePath();
        line.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Gray);
        line.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reactHorzLine);
        return line;
    }
    Sprite generateVertLines(int x, int y)
    {
        line.graphics.beginPath();
        line.graphics.moveTo(x, y);
        line.graphics.lineTo(x, y+100);
        // this.line.graphics.closePath();
        line.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Gray);
        line.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reactVertLine);
        return line;
    }

    void generateBoard()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
        {   
            for(int j = 0; j< 5;j++)
            {
                //render horizontal lines
                if(j < 4)
                {
                    stage.addChild(generateHorzLines(xPos,yPos));
                }
                //render vertical lines
                if(i<4)
                {
                    stage.addChild(generateVertLines(xPos,yPos));
                }
                //render points
                stage.addChild(generateDots(xPos,yPos,5));
                xPos+=100;
            }
        yPos+=100;
        xPos = 100;
        }
    }

    void reactHorzLine(MouseEvent event)
    {
        line.graphics.fillColor(Color.Red);
    }
    void reactVertLine(MouseEvent event)
    {
        line.graphics.fillColor(Color.Green);
    }
    void reactCircle(MouseEvent event)
    {
        circle.graphics.fillColor(Color.Blue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You also can set default values for fields where you declare them `int xPos = 100;` This way you can reduce your constructor to `GameBoard(this.stage);` (a convenient form to initialize fields from constructor arguments, here you need `this` though)

Comment: Some recommendations regarding your code. It would be better to extend the GameBoard from Sprite (or DisplayObjectContainer). This way you can create a new instance of GameBoard and add this instance to the Stage. Using the "graphics" property on Sprite is okay, but if you only use Sprites for drawing vector graphics it would be more efficient to use the Shape class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of StageXL (0.12) has no support for vector graphics when using the WebGL renderer only the Canvas2D renderer is supported. This will change with the next versions where vector graphics are also supported with the WebGL renderer. In the meantime you can opt-out of the WebGL renderer to use the Canvas2D renderer.

```
// do this before you construct the Stage
StageXL.stageOptions.renderEngine = RenderEngine.Canvas2D;
```

Btw. you will get best performance by using Bitmaps/BitmapDatas in StageXL. They are based on textures which will be rendered much faster than vector graphics.

Comment: I included the  
`StageXL.stageOptions.renderEngine = RenderEngine.Canvas2D;`
in my Main.dart file which I call gameBoard in.  I found that information from one of your previous posts.  Could you give an example on using Bitmaps/BitmapDatas to render shapes? I am assuming it is quite similar to as3.

Comment: To use BitmapDatas you need textures (like PNG images) or even better texture atlases where all images are combined on one big image - this will boost performance in WebGL. You can find some samples on this GitHub repo: https://github.com/bp74/StageXL_Samples/tree/master/example/basic/texture_atlas